# Why is the render () function executed twice?

Tags: reactjs

I created a project with create react app and added the following code to App.js. However, the render () function is executed twice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('새로고침')
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

from App.js, take out the Strict Mode component and you will see that is rendered just once.

Here Dan Abramov refer to that:
https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1090753235495862273